# Using a dictionary from a code-behind causes a key error in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am programming a web application in visual basic using visual studio 2005 and .NET 2.0.  My code behind (Default.aspx.vb) looks like this.

```
Partial Public Class frmDefault
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected PageData As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        PageData("text") = "Hello World!"
    End Sub
End Class
```

In Default.aspx, I have

```
<%=PageData("text")%>
```

When put on the live server (which would get about 40 unique hits per day), this would result in sporadic "The given key was not present in the dictionary." errors with the following stacktrace:

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
at ASP.default_aspx.__RenderContent2(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at ASP.forms_glass_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I'd see these in the log 1-2 times per day but never got the error myself while debugging, testing, or using the live application.

In order to log more information, I tried to catch the key error by putting this in the form class:

```
Protected Function GetPageData(ByRef Key As String) As String
    Try
        Return PageData(Key)
    Catch Ex As Exception
        'Log the exception
    End Try
End Function
```

and using this in Default.aspx:

```
<%=GetPageData("text")%>
```

Ever since I shipped this change (over a month ago), I have not logged a single key exception.

(1) What could cause the original code to generate key exceptions?

(2) Why does the updated code not generate similar key exceptions?

Comment: I would split out the PageData(key) on a new line before the Return.  The return statement could somehow be messing with your error logging.